# www and non-www passing to jquery not understand

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I was create an handler for upload images in ck-editor. This is the jquery for call the handler given below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                CKEDITOR.replace('<%=ckeditcms.ClientID %>',
      { filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'http://joinmbw.in/Upload.ashx' }); //path to “Upload.ashx”
            });
        </script>
```

the  problem is in "filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'http:// joinmbw.in/Upload.ashx' "...
the client reach the site with http:// www.joinmbw.in , so that the "filebrowserImageUploadUrl" is not redirect to the Upload.ashx... if i change the "filebrowserImageUploadUrl" to "filebrowserImageUploadUrl:'http:// www.joinmbw.in/Upload.ashx' " it works...

But i want it works  both the domain with www and non-www ...

I was tried this inside webconfig file.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

but it says element system.webserver has invalid child element rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you error statement *element system.webserver has invalid child element rewrite.*

You need to install [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) on your web server.

You can download required extension from the link [URL Rewrite Module 2.0](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite#additionalDownloads)

Comment: is there any other options than that url rewrite ??

Comment: @Saravana, If you want to use `rewrite`, as per my experiance then you have to install the extension